# Find corresponding elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of divs with IDs going from "c1", "c2", "c3", etc. I would like to add a class to corresponding elements with IDs going from "b1", "b2", "b3" when hovering one of these divs. So c1 corresponds to b1, c2 to b2 and so on.

What is the best way to do this in jQuery?

I have been trying to experiment with some code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux9muxzq/1/) - obviously I couldn't make it work.

Html:

```
<div id="c1" class="event">c1</div>
<div id="c2" class="event">c2</div>
<div id="c3" class="event">c3</div>

<div id="t1" class="target">t1</div>
<div id="t2" class="target">t2</div>
<div id="t3" class="target">t3</div>
```

Js:

```
$('.event').hover(function() {
  var getID = $(this).attr('id'); // get event ID
  $(".target").each(function() {
    var getTargetID = $(this).attr('id'); // get target ID
    $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + xxx).addClass('newClas'); // <--- how to map the corresponding elements?
  });
});
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Can you show the HTML and tell us on hovering the `.target`, what should happen? Your code and question seems confusing.

Comment: I have updated my question with the markup as well... So when hovering c1, I would like to add a class to b1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) and use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the element at index. No need to depend upon IDs.

```
var targets = $(".target").removeClass('newClass');
var events = $('.event');
events.hover(function() {
    //Get current element index
    var index = events.index(this);

    targets.eq(index).addClass('newClass');
}, function() {
    targets.removeClass('newClass');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fqgzd4o9/1/)

If you still want to use Ids

```
events.hover(function() {
    var number = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    $('#t' + number).addClass('newClass');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0cwtecgL/1/)

Comment: This one is definitely the most flexible solution, but how does index work? Does it require the event target elements to appear in the correct order in the html?

Comment: @Meek, You understanding is correct, event target elements to appear in the correct order. However also provided answer for IDS as well

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
$('[id^=c]').on('hover',function() {
  var hoverIDnumber = $(this).attr('id').charAt($(this).length -1);
  $('#b'+hoverIDnumber+'').addCass('newclass');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".target").removeClass('newClass');
  $('.event').hover(function() {
     var getID = $(this).attr('id').replace('c','t'); // get event ID

      $('#'+getID+'').addCLass('newClas');
  });
```

Comment: An explanation of what you have done and why it works would be helpful

Comment: actuly you told that c1 chnage to t1 so i just replace the  c to t and rest id will be same. that will change the row color on hover

Answer (score 0):

I'd use data tags to achieve the desired result. Get the ID of the hovered element and find the element with the corresponding data-id

```
$('.event').on('mouseover', function() {
  var getID = $(this).attr('id'); // get event ID
  $("[data-id='" + getID + "']").toggleClass('newClass')
});
```

See the fiddle for the html:

https://jsfiddle.net/ux9muxzq/1/

Answer (score 0):

The approach below works fine. My assumption is that the `targetId` can easily be derived from the `sourceId`.

```js
$('.event').hover(function() {
  var sourceID = $(this).attr('id');
  var targetID = "t" + sourceID.substring(1); // tune this for your actual ids
  $(".target").removeClass('newClass');
  $("#" + targetID).addClass('newClass');
});
```

```css
.event    { background: #ddf; margin: 2px }
.target   { background: #dfd; margin: 2px }
.newClass { border: 3px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1" class="event">c1</div>
<div id="c2" class="event">c2</div>
<div id="c3" class="event">c3</div>
<br>
<div id="t1" class="target">t1</div>
<div id="t2" class="target">t2</div>
<div id="t3" class="target">t3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Delegate the `mouseenter` event on all `div.event` (`$('.event')`)
- Store the index number of `this` (`var idx = $(this).index()`)
- Use `.eq()` and `idx-1` as the parameter to locate the `div.target` (`$('.target').eq(idx-1)`)
- Then add the class to it (`.addClass('b'+idx));`)
- If you want a temporary class change, replace `.on('mouseenter',` with `.hover(`.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.event').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var idx = $(this).index();
  $('.target').eq(idx - 1).addClass('b' + idx);
});
```

```css
.b1,
.b2,
.b3 {
  color: #930;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
div {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: #DED;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1" class="event">c1</div>
<div id="c2" class="event">c2</div>
<div id="c3" class="event">c3</div>

<div id="t1" class="target">t1</div>
<div id="t2" class="target">t2</div>
<div id="t3" class="target">t3</div>
```